# Holder Inequality

Tags: analysis, inequality, banach-spaces, lp-spaces, integral-inequality

I have a problem with the demonstration of this inequality ('m following Royden) :

If $p$ and $q$ are nonnegative numbers such that
$\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}$ and if $f \in L^p$ and $g \in L^q$, then $f\cdot g \in L^1$ and
$$\int |fg| \leqslant ||f||_p \cdot ||g||_q$$ 
Without loss of generality suppose $f,g \geqslant 0$

Set $h(x)=g(x)^{q-1}=g(x)^{p/q}$,since $q-1=q/p$ also $g(x)=h(x)^{q-1}=h(x)^{p/q}$

Thus for $t \in \bf{R}$:
$$ptf(x)g(x)= ptf(x)h(x)^{p-1} \leqslant (h(x)+tf(x))^p-h(x)$$ (because of lemma). Hence
$$pt \int fg \leqslant \int |h+tf|^p-\int h^p = ||h+tf||^p-||h||^p$$ and
$$pt \int fg \leqslant (||h||+t||f||)^p-||h||^p$$
Now is the passage that I do not understand:

Differentiating both sides with respect to t at t=0, we get
$$p \int fg \leqslant p ||f|| \cdot ||h||_p^{p-1}=p||f|| \cdot ||g||$$

I do not see why I can derive from both sides of an INEQUALITY..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one **knows the value at one point** and has an inequality, one can actually derive an inequality for the derivative as follows:

Let us assume for simplicity that $f : [0,\infty) \to \Bbb{R}$ fulfils $f(x) \leq 0$ for all $x$ **and** $f(0) = 0$.

Then (**if $f$ is (one-sidedly) differentiable at $0$**),

$$
f'(0) = \lim_{h \downarrow 0} \frac{f(h) - f(0)}{h} \leq 0,
$$

because the denominator is positive and the numerator is $\leq 0$.

In your case, apply this to the difference

$$
f(t) = pt \int fg \,dx - (\Vert h \Vert +t \Vert f \Vert)^p + \Vert h \Vert^p.
$$

As seen in the proof above, it is important to note that $f(0) = 0$ and we have $f(t) \leq 0$ for all $t$ by what you have shown.